# How find the point moved on optical flow farneback opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, opticalflow

I have this code of the opencv examples:

```
def draw_flow(img, flow, step=16):
    h, w = img.shape[:2]
    y, x = np.mgrid[step/2:h:step,step/2:w:step].reshape(2, -1)
    fx, fy = flow[y,x].T
    lines = np.vstack([x, y, x+fx, y+fy]).T.reshape(-1,2,2)
    lines = np.int32(lines)
    vis = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    for (x1, y1), (x2, y2) in lines:
        cv2.line(vis, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (0,255,255), 3)
```

But i would like know how find the point that will go move, i say the lines.

I tried put the values that was different in one array but many values was moved (Including the lines).

Someone help me?